# Jest mocks not running when in helper file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I know jest does some re-write magic before executing tests, I'm just trying to figure out how to mock `fs.lstat` in a helper file.

let's take an example module:

```js
/* module.js */
import { lstat } from 'fs';

export default function () {
  return lstat();
}
```

and a minimal example test file that works:

```js
/* module.test.js */
import module from './module';

// start
import * as fs from 'fs';
jest.mock('fs');
const mockedFs = fs as jest.Mocked<typeof fs>;
mockedFs.lstat.mockReturnValue(42);
// end

test('test', () => {
  expect(module()).toBe(42);
});
```

That works as is.  If I take everything between the `start` and `end` comments and move it into another file, then import that, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @Nobody, I see you want to give away big bounties to some answers, but could you please pick the deserving ones. Mine here https://stackoverflow.com/q/69273262/2945027 wasn't worth it at all, so I deleted it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev -- lol I'm just giving them randomly

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: Ok, got it. But I was confused. I even discussed that on Meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412387/2945027

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.

Leaving just `jest.mock('fs')` in actual test file allows mock functions to run from other imports.